# Error when extract embedded Files from Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I found a very good solution about extracting embedded files in word. But this solution fails at ExtractFile function with error "subscript out of range" when I extract file. exe or .txt
Please help me.
[How to extract embedded Files from Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66088756/how-to-extract-embedded-files-from-word)

```
Sub ExtractFile(ByVal A0, ByVal A1, ByVal A2, ByVal A3, ByVal A4, ByVal OleFN, ByVal Z0, ByVal Z1, ByVal Z2, ByVal Z3, ByVal Z4, ByVal Z5, ByVal TextFN, ByVal offset, ByVal length)
    Dim i, j, nFile As Long
    Dim L() As Byte
    Dim B() As Byte
    
    If Not FileOpen(OleFN, B) Then Exit Sub
    For i = 0 To UBound(B) - 64
        If IIf(A0 < 0, B(i) < A0 * -1, B(i) = A0) And IIf(A1 = 256, B(i + 1) > 0, B(i + 1) = A1) And IIf(A2 = 256, B(i + 2) > 0, B(i + 2) = A2) And IIf(A3 = 256, B(i + 3) > 0, B(i + 3) = A3) And IIf(A4 = 256, B(i + 4) > 0, B(i + 4) = A4) Then Exit For
    Next
    If Z0 < 257 Then
        For j = UBound(B) - 16 To i - 64 Step -1
            If IIf(Z0 = 256, B(j) > 0, B(j) = Z0) And IIf(Z1 = 256, B(j + 1) > 0, B(j + 1) = Z1) And IIf(Z2 = 256, B(j + 2) > 0, B(j + 2) = Z2) And B(j + 3) = Z3 And IIf(Z4 = 256, B(j + 4) > 0, B(j + 4) = Z4) And IIf(Z5 = 256, B(j + 5) > 0, B(j + 5) = Z5) Then Exit For
        Next
    Else
        j = UBound(B)
    End If
    ReDim L(0 To j - i + length)
    For j = 0 To IIf(UBound(L) + i + offset > UBound(B), UBound(L) + i - length, UBound(L))
        L(j) = B(i + j + offset)
    Next
    nFile = FreeFile
    Open TextFN For Binary Access Write As nFile
    Put nFile, , L
    Close nFile
End Sub
```

*ReDim* encountered an error with message: "subscript out of range"

Comment: You don't tell us exactly where you're getting the error....

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams, I'm using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66088756/how-to-extract-embedded-files-from-word solution to extract ole object from Word file. It's ok with pdf file, but error occurred when exe or txt file embedded to Word file. I debugged and found an error in ExtractFile function, with message: "subscript out of range" at line 107. PLease help me to fix it.

Comment: Please *edit your question* to add the relevant part(s) of your code and indicate which exact line you're getting the error on - there's no way for us to be sure which line is line 107...

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams, just edited my post. Can you rerun the code with my case to understand the error I got?